# Ember how to resolve Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'SEP'

Tags: ember.js

I am learning ember.  Still in the early stages where I am unable to get clarity on high level connectivity between `Controller`, `Route`, `Model` (or when to use which one etc). This question may be silly. Probably I am missing something very fundamental.

I get `Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'SEP'` when I use this piece of code in my `about` template.

```
 {{#each thing in something}}
      <p>{{thing.name}}</p>
 {{#/each}}
```

app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({})

App.NAMES=[{ name: 'first name' },{ name: 'another name' }];

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');  
});

App.AboutController = Ember.Controller.extend({ 
  something: function() {
    return App.NAMES;
  }.property()
});
```

I also tried moving `something` to

```
App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  something: function() {
    return App.NAMES;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{/each}}` instead of `{{#/each}}` :-)